# Log all database objects accessed by JDBC

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, logging, jdbc

Is there a way to log all database tables (and maybe other objects) that the application running within Tomcat reads from/write to? All of the database access is performed either via Hibernate (wired through Spring) or Sql2o.

We are in process of migrating a legacy database, and it would be nice to automatically separate tables that are actually used from the ones that are pure legacy (and we've got lots of those!).

Thanks!

Comment: You can establish a JDBC connection and say 'select * from tab', if tables alone are needed.

Comment: You can log all sql request (hibernate have option for it), But isn't it easier just look into your mapping? Dont know what Sql2o is, but think it can log sql too.

Comment: IMHO not one 100% reliable. You might however try to configure something like http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/ and then e.g. after one week try to grep each of the legacy database table names in the log file. Those not found by the grep has not been used at least for the one test week.

Comment: @talex - looking into mappings might or might not suffice as you might execute native SQL trough Hibernate API. Anyway I think whether that is an option depends also on the amount of code done per Sql2o. But I agree that analyzing the application is probably better that analyzing logs with actuall SQL access.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am trying to set up P6spy now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Aspect since you are already using Spring, and monitor all your read/write services, so every time any of it is called, you can log it.

It should be quite easy, define new aspect (f.e. MyAspect), define before/after or round actions (which will log your table names somewhere), and just put the annotation on your services (@MyAspect).

Another way is to create triggers on your tables (not sure if that is an option), but I'd preffer an aspect... It's much cleaner approach.